# if a string exist (including a variable), flip it using awk or sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a csv file like this:

```
,College Level Math 55,Elementary Algebra 112
,Elementary Algebra 79,
,College Level Math 102,Elementary Algebra 54
,,College Level Math 54
```

I need an awk or sed command that does the following

if `College Level Math *,Elementary Alegrbra *` exist flip it so it looks like

```
Elementary Algebra *, College Level Math *
```

Desired output

```
,Elementary Algebra 112,College Level Math 55
,Elementary Algebra 79,
,Elementary Algebra 54,College Level Math 102
,,College Level Math 54
```

My problem is I don't know the number at the end or if it will be 2 or 3 digits.

I know how to flip it, if it was the exact same text everytime

```
sed -e 's/College Level Math,Elementary Algebra/Elementary Algebra,College Level Math/g'
```

But the number variable has me at a loss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed` with extended regex:

```
sed -r 's/(College Level Math.*?),(Elementary Algebra.*)/\2,\1/g' filepath
```

`\1` is the first captured group (`College Level Math.*?`)

`\2` is the second captured group (`Elementary Algebra.*`)

Thus the above `sed` performs a replacement operation from `\1,\2` to `\2,\1`

---

The above regex will serve for general cases, but it will fail on cases like these:

```
,College Level Math 55,Elementary Algebra 111,Elementary Algebra 112
#\1=College Level Math 55,Elementary Algebra 111

,College Level Math 55,College Level Math 55,Elementary Algebra 112
#\1=College Level Math 55,College Level Math 55
```

So it's better not to use greedy regex like `.*`, instead if the entries are comma separated, you should use this:

```
sed -r 's/(College Level Math[^,]*),(Elementary Algebra[^,]*)/\2,\1/g' filepath
```

Comment: this looks like the cleanest example, thank you so much. I had tried using .* but not with the ? (also missing the parentheses). Is the \2,\1/g the part that flips them? and does the location in the csv matter, like if its column 7 and 8 first 1 and 2? or is the 1 and 2 just referring to the college and elementary pieces in the parentheses?

Comment: @moore1emu 1 refers to the first group (here `College Level Math.*?`)  inside parentheses, 2 is the second, and so on... So the answer for `is the 1 and 2 just referring to the college and elementary pieces in the parentheses? ` is yes...

Comment: @moore1emu there's some piftalls of that regex you need to be concerned about, I updated my answer with a bit explanation..

Answer (score 1):

Use [captures](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) in your regular expression:

```
sed 's/\(College Level Math[^,]*\),\(Elementary Algebra[^,]*\)/\2,\1/'
```

Edit: It has been pointed out to me on a previous answer of mine that escaping the parentheses in order to convert them from a literal to a metacharacter is not POSIX compliant and thus not as portable as it could be. If portability is a concern for you, you can omit the `\` and just use the `-r` option to enable extended regular expression syntax, as in Jahid's answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} $2!="" && $3!=""{t=$2;$2=$3;$3=t} 1' file
,Elementary Algebra 112,College Level Math 55
,Elementary Algebra 79,
,Elementary Algebra 54,College Level Math 102
,,College Level Math 54
```

Comment: Loving the use of awk, but if the columns are not always 2 and 3 in the csv, wouldn't this break? or am I reading this wrong. I know my example didn't mention the various places the columns would be, I was mainly just focused on fixing the number variable part

Comment: I don't know if "break" is the right term but the script certainly would need to be changed if your posted sample input doesn't match your real input.

Answer (score 0):

another version

```
sed 's/\(,College Level Math [0-9]\{2,3\}\)\(,Elementary Algebra [0-9]\{2,3\}\)/\2\1/' urfile
```

Answer (score 0):

For given sample input, this should work:

`$ sed -r 's/(,)(College Level Math)(.*)(Elementary Algebra)(.*)/\1\4\3\2\5/g' file`

Above was `GNU sed`.

For other `sed`:

`$ sed 's/\(,\)\(College Level Math\)\(.*\)\(Elementary Algebra\)\(.*\)/\1\4\3\2\5/g' file`

It is capturing each line in 5 capture groups which are later back referenced as `\1\4\3\2\5`

Refer sed back referencing: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-4